# What is the best practice for base model in MVC 4 project?

Tags: c#, architecture, model, asp.net-mvc-4

I am starting a new MVC project and it is definetly known that each view required the next items: user language, timezone and few user settings referred to city, country, etc. So, I am going to make some base entity where to put this properties. But some view would be type of PagedList (class from opensource MvcPaging library). And I am not sure how to combine Base model and PagedList in one object?
I thank about interfaces but I read that it is more complex rather then using classes.

Answer (score 1):

sounds like you should look into inheritance:

```cs
public class BaseModel
{
    public string UserLanguage { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class SomePageModel : BaseModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public PagedList<Whatever> PagedStuff { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

In this case `SomePageModel` inherits all properties of `BaseModel`. You don't need to use PagedList as a Model. You can use SomePageModel as a model for a view, which has inside the PagedList. In this case you'd write in the view:

```cs
@model [namespace].SomePageModel

//to access paged stuff:
@Model.PagedStuff
```

But really your question lucks specifics and it's hard to direct you in the correct direction based on the information you've provided thus far.

Comment: Yep, but I am going to use PagedList<T> model which is from MvcPaging library, so there is no possibility to combine BaseModel and PagedList<T>